# Show html tag by tag with a delay using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem that I spend many time reading and trying to solve but didnt work.

I have to simulate a chat like this:

[image: Chat first interaction]

But I cannot find out a way to do a delay between each one of bubbles, they always show at the same time, I tried to use a lot of functions I found online, like setTimeout, await sleep with promises and etc. None of them worked, the bubbles always show at same time and many times the delay itself dont even work, they show before the delay time has over.

Do any one has an idea how to do it? I only need to know how to do this the logic I work myself. So basically I need to know how to say to Reactjs: "Show a empty page, after 2 seconds, show first bubble, after 2 second,s show second bubble".

Code example: Using states:

```
renderChat(){
            let bubbles = this.state.bubbles;
            if(this.state.renderSecondBubbles){
              bubbles.push(this.renderBubbleResponse(this.state.name));
              bubbles.push(<BubbleUs><p>Hello {this.state.name}</p></BubbleUs>)
             }else{
                if(this.state.renderFirstBubbles){
                  bubbles.push(<BubbleUs><p>Hello</BubbleUs>)
                  bubbles.push(<BubbleUs><p>What is your name?</p></BubbleUs>)
                }
              }
}

render(){
 return(
  <div>
   {this.renderChat()}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Example not using states:

```
render(){
 return(
 <div>
  <BubbleUs>Your account was created</BubbleUs>
  <BubbleUs>Now, its time to choose your payment method</BubbleUs>
 </div>
 )
}
```

Thanks a lot people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would certainly need some code from you. Do you render these bubbles based on some state tree, or do you just create them straight in the component `render()` method?

If the second one, I believe you can simulate a timeout response using the [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) in the component:

```
import React from 'react';

export class SampleMessages extends React.Component {
  contructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      interval: null,
      messages: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const newMessages = this.state.messages.concat([ 'New message' ]);

      this.setState({ messages: newMessages });
    }, 1000);

    this.setState({ interval });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.interval);
  }

  render() {
    const { messages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {messages.map((text, index) =>
          <p key={Math.random() + index}>
            {text}
          </p>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That's true, sorry @JoeClay, edited the possible answer in 

Comment: I have the two cases, there is parts that render using state but at other pages only render, I will update the answer with a example of my code.